# AWS Java SDK DynamoDBClient class file not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to use the AWS SDK to connect to DynamoDB.

I have the following code:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController
{
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index()
    {
        AmazonSNSClient amazonSNSClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
        AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonDynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I show the SNS client to show that this constructor does work. If I use any 1.11.x version of the SDK, I get a compilation error on the DynamoDBClient line

```
cannot access com.amazonaws.client.AwsSyncCLientPrarams
```

If I use a 1.10.x version of the SDK, I can compile this code.

Is there an API change I'm not aware of or is the 1.11.x branch broken?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a conflicting dependency in my pom that was pulling in an older version of aws-java-sdk-core